# Set table rows height to character height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use a good ol' `<table>` as a striped "canvas" to draw an ascii chart ... Erm. like this:

[image]

How can I go from *left* to *right* ?
For the optic illusion to work, I need the table rows height to equals char heights so there is no visible vertical space between chars.

I have tried following css tweaking with no success (this code gives the *left* result) :

```
  <table class="table-responsive table-condensed table-striped table-collapse">
    <tr>
    <td class='row-mini'><div class='div-mini'><code>______┌ </code></div></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td class='row-mini'><div class='div-mini'><code>______│</code></div></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td class='row-mini'><div class='div-mini'><code>____┌─┤</code></div></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td class='row-mini'><div class='div-mini'><code>____│ ⋮</code></div></td></tr>
    </table>
```

with css:

```
.row-mini {
    padding:0px; margin:0;
}
.div-mini {
   height: 10 px; 
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: instead of height you can use line-height with no border spacing-- demo https://jsfiddle.net/b78nhw3y/

Comment: @Tasos Because it's bootstrap styled, I had to remove the (badly named?) table-condensed class to make it work. If you repost your comment as answer (+ my edit), I'll accept it. jsfiddle is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use line-height with no border spacing and remove table-condensed class

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/81wu4cp8/

**Html**

```
 <table class="table-responsive table-striped table-collapse">
    <tr>
    <td class='row-mini'><div class='div-mini'><code>______┌ </code></div></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td class='row-mini'><div class='div-mini'><code>______│</code></div></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td class='row-mini'><div class='div-mini'><code>____┌─┤</code></div></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td class='row-mini'><div class='div-mini'><code>____│ ⋮</code></div></td></tr>
    </table>
```

**Css**

```
.row-mini {
    padding:0px; margin:0;
}
.div-mini {
   line-height: 11px; 
   overflow: hidden;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

**Result**

[image]